# Following Android build instructions - emulator fails with "No initial system image for this configuration"

Tags: java, android, ubuntu, build, virtualbox

Good afternoon,

I've been trying for some time now to get the Android source to build. I have followed the instructions here:
http://source.android.com/source/building.html

The configuration step I have chosen is: "full-eng". The machine is Ubuntu 11.10, 32-bit, AMD x6 1090T processor, 4 GB of RAM running inside VirtualBox on a Windows 7 64-bit host.

I am able to get through the build process (or so it seems), with the last status lines reading:

```
...
target Dex: android.core.tests.libcore.package.com.no-core-tests-res
target Dex: android.core.tests.libcore.package.dalvik.no-core-tests-res
target Dex: android.core.tests.libcore.package.libcore.no-core-tests-res
target Dex: android.core.tests.libcore.package.org.no-core-tests-res
make: *** [out/target/common/obj/APPS/android.core.tests.libcore.package.com.no-core-tests-res_intermediates/noproguard.classes-with-local.dex] Killed
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
sean@sean-VirtualBox:~/src/android$
```

When I try to run the emulator (per the seemingly oversimplified instructions from the page above), I get this:

```
sean@sean-VirtualBox:~/src/android$ emulator
emulator: ERROR: No initial system image for this configuration!
```

I've had pretty good luck using the emulator from my local Windows environment, but I'd like to get the Android source built so I can start learning more about it. In absence of a clear answer, I would take any alternative instructions for getting the source to build and run on the emulator.

I also have a G2x, G2 and G1 at my disposal if I got real desperate and needed to use a physical device, but I'd really like to get the emulator to work first. I also imagine that I'll need to know where the output image files went if I were to flash a device. (Googles instructions dubiously omitted elaboration on where the output went and what files are used when flashing or running the emulator)

Thanks!

-Sean

Answer (score 2):

The basic steps are:

```
$ cd <path/to/android/source>
$ . build/envsetup.sh
$ lunch full-eng
$ make # should finish without errors
$ ./out/host/linux-x86/bin/emulator
```

and your emulator should start. Notice that running the emulator inside a VM would be really slow.

Comment: Gonna try it when I get home. In the process, I installed a new Ubuntu64 copy since the instructions mention that 32-bit builds are "experiemental". Also, the performance on this VM with VTx (2 emulated cores) and other acceleration is simply amazing. Full screen works beautifully! I'll post my results tonight. Thanks!

Comment: Closer... on my fresh 64-bit install, the last lines give me this:

Done!
Install: out/target/product/generic/system/app/Settings.odex
...
Target system fs image: out/target/product/generic/obj/PACKAGING/systemimage_intermediates/system.img
Install system fs image: out/target/product/generic/system.img
..
Now, it looks like I'm missing an AVD to run the emulator with. Those pesky instructions make it seem easy to get up and running. Off to figure out how to create the AVD from command line. :)
Thanks for that much. Almost there...

Comment: http://groups.google.com/group/android-platform/browse_thread/thread/91ff18e034acf951
This thread allowed me to launch the emulator (finally!).. now, the problem is that it appears to just hang. I have to kill the process, otherwise, it's completely unresponsive. Gonna try more tomorrow. Thanks again!